# Add a masking overlay to highlight certain areas on an interactive mapboxgl map

Tags: performance, webgl, overlay, mask, mapbox-gl-js

I am building a website where users can search for specific places or areas on a map with some filters like "park", "supermarket", "cafe", etc. For example, a user should be able to find all suitable areas in a city that are near a park but also are at least 1 km away from a highway (for some reason). To do so, after the user has specified some filters, I want to add an overlay that masks all areas that don't satisfy these filters while still allowing the user to zoom and pan freely. I am using MapboxGL for building the map.

My first attempt was to use [Turf](https://turfjs.org/docs/) on my geojson data to perform the necessary operations, i.e. converting the current viewport to a bounding box polygon, union all needed geojson features to one polygon and mask the difference between them and then simply add the result as a Fill-Layer on the mapbox  map as seen in the image below.

[image: I don't have enough reputation yet to embed this image directly]

While this approach does work for simple overlays it doesn't scale and needs a lot of time to perform the necessary operations on the data when used with a lot of geojson data and more filters.

Instead of working with the geojson directly I thought it might be better to use a canvas overlay and render the mask layer with webgl to improve the performance. I found a [mapbox example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-style-layer/) for overlaying a custom style layer on a map, but unfortunately, I have never used webgl before and I'm not really sure how I would render such an overlay with this custom layer.

Is using a custom overlay with webgl the right approach to solve my problem? Or is there an obvious option (or another library) for this task I haven't considered yet?

Comment: I'm not sure. Your turf method is the one I have used before, but it sounds like your data is quite complex. Maybe you should be performing that operation on the server? Sometimes different combinations of similarly-named Turf operations have very different performance characteristics.

Comment: @SteveBennett Hm, I tested some alternatives and it seems turf.mask() is in general faster than turf.difference(), but I couldn't improve the performance a lot, unfortunately. To be honest, I don't think using Turf alone can solve my problem. Maybe any other ideas or thoughts on the custom layer approach with webgl?

Comment: That's outside my area of expertise.